# SignalR with Office Apps - "Error Access Denied error while negotiate connection."

Tags: cors, signalr, office-app

I have three projects.

- SignalR Host Application

  - Enabled CORS and JSONP settings
- Office Apps application (manifest)

  - in the masifest > App Domains settings, included the SignalR Host Application URL
- Office Apps Web application

  - modified the `$.connection.hub.url.` since I am accessing cross origin host

I am accessing cross-origin SignalR Host Application from  Office Apps Web application. When I start the connection from hub I got `"Error Access Denied"` error while negotiate connection.". But Its working in Browser (for this I have created html application with same code and run in browser).

**Environment**: `jquery-1.10.2.js`, `jquery.signalR-2.2.1`, Office 2016

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you monitor the calls to to your SignalR  app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. Office apps requires SSL Connection to signalR Server.

```
$.connection.hub.url = "https://localhost/Hub/signalr";
```